# using "com.github.bumptech.glide" in offline mode in android studio

Tags: android, android-glide, android-tv

I am working on an application for android TV and the default tv activity (Browse fragment to be specific) uses glide for image loading. Due to certain reason I cannot get access to open internet(setting the proxy in http setting is not helping either), and hence every time I try to build the project I get the error message saying -
***Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.4.+
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog***

Please suggest a solution for the problem.
Also I don't require glide library, its just that it is a part of the default code provided by google for android TV apps.

Comment: If you don't require it, why don't you just remove it?

Comment: @KNeerajLal it has been used at multiple places within the project , and when i try to remove those and run the application , the application simply crashes

Comment: Then your statement _I don't require glide library_ is wrong.

Comment: @KNeerajLal While creating application for android tv , the activity already includes code for the fragment. Although I don't require the feature offered by glide but it has been used(by default) at several places within the code. I tried removing all the dependencies from the code but then the application crashes

Answer (score 1):

To use Glide library in offline mode you can download its corresponding jar from [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide) and add it to your `app/libs` folder. Sync the project and it should be good.

The main disadvantage is that you will need to manually update the library, when an updated jar is released.